# setOnLongClickListener on a ListView doesn't fire

Tags: android, android-layout

what is wrong with this code?
i try to add a long click listener to an listview, but can't get it right for some reason:

```
package ch.futurecom.adaptertest;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AdapterTestActivity extends ListActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setLongClickable(true);
        lv.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(AdapterTestActivity.this, "long clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;    
            }
        });

        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items)));
    }
}
```

pastebin links:
AdapterTestActivity.java -> http://pastebin.com/Pw30EkEz
row.xml -> http://pastebin.com/6FajncHT

thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener as

```
ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){ 
                   @Override 
                   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) 
                  { 
                       Toast.makeText(AdapterTestActivity .this, "LongClicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  } 
             });
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped me! Just a small note, you need to add a return;

Answer (score 3):

use `setOnItemLongClickListener` insted of `setOnLongClickListener`

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener (new OnItemLongClickListener() {
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //do your stuff here
  }
});
```